# How to provide Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs) to the CloudFront distribution using CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cloudformation

I have tried:

`"Aliases": ["www.samplewebsite.com","samplewebsite.com"]`

But I am getting this error:

`Property validation failure: [Encountered unsupported properties in {/DistributionConfig/Origins/0}: [Aliases]]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, so the problem seems to be with the *JSON* object structure that you are using for creating the *CloudFront* distribution.

In oder to add the alternate `CNAME` to your *Cloudfront* distribution, you need to add the key `"Aliases"` under the `"DistributionConfig"` object and not under `"DistributionConfig/Origins"`.

So basically the property `"Aliases"` is defined as child object of `"DistributionConfig"`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have added Aliases under "DistributionConfig/Origins", now I have changed. It's working. Thank you Priyanka :)